# Apply Planning to Web search

Tags: artificial-intelligence

This is a homework, the question is : How would you apply the ideas of planning to Web search? Please answer at a high level; a paragraph or two will be sufficient.

I'm not sure what is the high level of planning, and don't know where to start. I read some papers about the information retrieval and web search but still cant connect them with Planning. Hope someone can give me some hints, like the relationship of planning and information retrival or web search.

Comment: Web search is an application. AI planning has no applications. Someone's asking the impossible...

Comment: AI planning has no application? you might want to check out https://www.coursera.org/course/aiplan

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Still no answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which part of web-search you are referring to. I'm assuming your question is about connection between AI planning and Web-search in general.

A web-crawler is integral part of a search engine. I think there are a plethora of AI planning algorithms used in order to decide which type of pages to crawl next and at what frequency to crawl a domain.

The other area where AI planning helps in Ad-Bidding. I'm not so sure about the applications specifically what kind of algorithms are used. May be do some google search to figure out.